# Add "referer" to header when using ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, http-headers, http-referer

I'm using ShellExecute to open the user's *default browser* to a specific web site.

I'd like to add a referer field to the URL.

Is this possible to do while continuing to use ShellExecute?

If not, any other suggestions to get a users default browser to open a URL with referer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referrer is part of the HTTP protocol. ShellExecute opens an app which then processes the URL, by sending an HTTP request. It's that app that specifies the referrer.

The very best you could do would be to include something in the URL and process it at the HTTP server end (presumably you are in control of the server end).

Comment: Darn, David, I was afraid of that. I believe that Indy lets me populate a header with the referer. Is there any way to start the process with Indy and then somehow open the results in a Delphi-owned browser window (rather than the user's default browser)?

Comment: @Robert I think you are stuffed if you want the URL to open in a *real* browser. You could put together a `TWebBrowser` based solution that would be hosted inside your app. Not sure whether that helps you because I don't know what your ultimate goal is!

Comment: Thanks, David, as usual for your help.  It just occurred to me that I can hit the site (which I don't control) in Indy to get the "credit" in their logs for sending traffic. I'll ignore the result. And then, as I've been doing, just shell out to the site's URL w/o the referer info...  Thanks for helping me think about this.

Comment: @robert just to be on the safe side you might want to check it over with the site that you are hitting