# Can't get my referer code to actually result in Google Analytics showing the referral

Tags: delphi, google-analytics, http-referer

Would the code below be all that is necessary to add a referer tag to an HTML request?

I have tested this code on my personal site and although I can see referrals from other sites appear in Google Analytics' reports, a referer named mysite doesn't appear, even if I wait a day or two to make sure GA has updated its reports.

```
IDhttp1.Create(Self);
IDhttp1.HandleRedirects := TRUE;
IDhttp1.Request.Referer := 'http://www.mysite.com';
IDhttp1.Get(URL); // ignore result. Just done to hit the site with the referer string
```

Follow-up to [Add "referer" to header when using ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067990/add-referer-to-header-when-using-shellexecute).

Comment: How long do you wait to see the analytics report?  AFAIK, it is not updated in real-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Delphi but it looks like you're trying to request a page programmatically. However, this probably won't execute the Google Analytics JavaScript code to register the pageview.

Comment: Ah ha! It hadn't occurred to me that retrieving a page's html without a browser would prevent the GA JavaScript from running.

Comment: +1, but how does GA report / filter out bots then? Presumably they are requesting pages programmatically and should by your assessment not execute GA's javascript?

Comment: Bot's aren't reported in Google Analytics unless they execute the JavaScript (which they usually don't). To get that data you need to use a log file analysis tool.

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on Google Analytics or this kind of tools to make conclusions, at least, without waiting a reasonable amount of time, as statistics are not real-time, but reasonable up to date.

Use a logger, a sniffer or check your server logs to see what's going to the server.

Is what I did to properly write this answer: the apache server access log show this:

[image: Apache log]

As you can see, the referrer is correctly reported to the server.

Comment: As I noted in my original post, I waited a day or two.  In fact, even many days later does not appear in GA.  By your "Is what I did to properly write this answer" do you mean you just tried a GetURL call and you say it in your log?

Comment: Yes, I performed a couple of GET's using Indy and then a tail command over the apache access log file.